# Shape Recognition From Maps (Orienteering)

Tags: objective-c, swift, image, opencv, image-recognition

I've recently been working on an orienteering based iPhone app. (For anyone who doesn't know, orienteering is a sport where a participant must flow a map to reach each 'control' in the numbered order.)

As part of the project I want to be able to detect a route from a photo of the users' map. The route always consists of `round circles` connected with straight lines. A `triangle` indicates the start of the course and a `double circle` indicates the finish. The route is not always the same colour. Below is an attached example map:

[image]

I want to be able to detect the route and later draw over it with GPS data however I am stumped with the image recognition. I have looked into `OpenCV` and a few other libraries despite the fact that many similar questions on StackOverflow have broken links.

**KEY NOTES**
- Detect route from map.
- Route always consists of same structure (`Triangle` followed by multiple `circles connected with straight lines` ending with a `double circle`.
- Route isn't always the same colour.
- Occasionally there are breaks in the `red line` - Which can be dealt with later.
- The accompanying number is **not** always in the same position in relation to the circle.
- I can set up a server for the image detection if easier, passing the photo from the phone to the server.
- Ideally a free service or library.

I understand the difficulty in detecting routes in complex maps with abstract backgrounds however any help, suggestions, links, tutorials would be much highly appreciated.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vision/
maybe

Comment: @AnthonyRoani That looks like a possible solution. I would be more interested in something that can do it it real time on the device though..